# Customizing the size of UI in wix installer

Tags: wix, installation

I created an installer using wix 3.10  and i localized it to be multilangual.
The UI of the InstallDirDlg in some languages like danish it cut off the text 
(the text is already built in , it is not written by )

[image: Cut off text]

Is it possible to maximize the size of the dialog in this case to fit the text ?

Comment: I updated my answer to your previous question. Unfortunately we live in very different timezones so I didn't reply earlier.

Comment: thanks very much ,, I checked it